# Android SQLite code feedback

Tags: java, android, sqlite, architecture

I have been through a few sqlite tutorials and wrote this code on my own to reinforce the principles. The tutorials I went through varied widely in a few areas so this is what I came up with as a combination of everything.

Other than the two classes I have listed below, All I have is one activity that adds, remove, inserts, update and display data from the database.

I am seeking any feedback whatsoever. However I have a few specific questions. Thanks in advance.

- When should I close the helper class or does garbage collection deal with it automatically?
- Should I create a Boxer POJO(Plain old java object to pass boxer data to and from the DAO?
- Was the DAO implementation Efficient?
- Does the code deviate from Java and Android best practices in anyway?
- Any constructive advice is welcome

Helper Class

```
public class BoxScoresHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "boxing_scores.db";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static BoxScoresHelper instance = null;

    public static BoxScoresHelper getInstance(Context context){

        if(instance == null){

            instance = new BoxScoresHelper(context);

        }

        return instance;
    }

    private BoxScoresHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);



    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(createBoxerSQLString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists " + BoxerDAO.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    private String createBoxerSQLString(){

        String boxerCreateString = "create table " + BoxerDAO.TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + BoxerDAO._ID + " Integer Primary Key AutoIncrement, " +
                BoxerDAO.BOXER_NAME +  " Text Not Null, " +
                BoxerDAO.WEIGHT_CLASS + " Text Not Null, " +
                BoxerDAO.WINS + " Integer Not Null, " +
                BoxerDAO.LOSSES + " Integer Not Null);";


        return boxerCreateString;
    }

}
```

DAO Class

```
public class BoxerDAO {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Boxer";
    public static final String _ID  = "_id";
    public static final String BOXER_NAME = "boxer_name";
    public static final String WEIGHT_CLASS = "weight_class";
    public static final String WINS = "wins";
    public static final String LOSSES ="losses";

    private final BoxScoresHelper myScoresHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myBoxerDB;

    public BoxerDAO(Context context){

        myScoresHelper = BoxScoresHelper.getInstance(context);

    }

    public Cursor query(String[] projection,String selection,String[] selectionArgs, String orderBy){

        Cursor cursor;
        myBoxerDB = myScoresHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = myBoxerDB.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);

        //myBoxerDB.close();

        return cursor;


    }

    public Cursor queryAll(){

        Cursor cursor;
        myBoxerDB = myScoresHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = myBoxerDB.rawQuery("Select * From " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        //myBoxerDB.close();
        return cursor;

    }

    public int delete(int id){

        int rowsDel;
        myBoxerDB = myScoresHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        rowsDel = myBoxerDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + " = " + id , null);

        //myBoxerDB.close();
        return rowsDel;

    }

    public long insert(ContentValues values){

        long insertId = -1;

        myBoxerDB = myScoresHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        insertId = myBoxerDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        //myBoxerDB.close();

        return insertId;

    }

    public int update(ContentValues values,String selection, String[] selectionArgs){

        int updatedRows;
        myBoxerDB = myScoresHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        updatedRows = myBoxerDB.update(TABLE_NAME, values, _ID + " = " + selection, selectionArgs);
        //myBoxerDB.close();

        return updatedRows;

    }   

}
```

Comment: IMHO this question would be more appropriate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review and delete your question here on Stack Overflow.